# Text inside table over image which hovers?

Tags: html, css, text, html-table, cell

I have created a table, and inside every cell, there is an image which has a "hover" effect. The image contains graphics + text (hardprinted).

Everything works good till the promoter of my site, told me to put "real" text over the JPG, and remove the printed text from image.

I have tried several things, but I couldn't find something. Maybe I messed "position".

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<table id="tablestyle">
<tr align="center">
    <td><a id="button" href="index.html"></a></td>
    <td><a id="button" href="index.html"></a></td>
    <td><a id="button" href="index.html"></a></td>
    <td><a id="button" href="index.html"></a></td>
    <td><a id="button" href="index.html"></a></td>
    <td><a id="button" href="index.html"></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And CSS

```
#button {
display: block;
width: 135px;
height: 34px;
background: url('images/navibutton.jpg') 50% bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
text-indent: -99999px;
position: static;
}
#button:hover {
background-position: 0 0;
}
#tablestyle {
margin: auto;
width: 900px;
}
```

I have tried to put text before a, after a, but whatever I try does not work. Or the cell totally loses position, or the text is hidden (or something else).

For the hover "effect" I use a 135x68 image. It's working.

Comment: The use of `before` and `after` doesn't generate "real" text (SEO-wise). You need to place text in your markup.

Comment: I improve my post, i meant the <a> which was hidden by default!